# How can I deploy my flexi-page via change sets?

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, metadata, change-set, flexipages

I created a flexi page. How can I deploy this to Production via change sets?

What should I add to change sets?  I can't see any "Flexi page" component in "Component Type"

Comment: I believe the underlying metadata type `FlexiPage` was invented and committed before product marketing got their hands on it and gave it a common name "Lightning Page"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to add Flexi Page into change set look for Lightning Page in Component type